# Executing multiple uninstallers with a single master uninstaller

Tags: installation, inno-setup, uninstallation

I have a master installer created using Inno Setup that executes a bunch of installers. Each installed app has its own uninstaller, and there is also an uninstaller created from the master installer.

The master installer doesn't do anything else besides running the other installers but it does produce an uninstaller for itself.

Is there anyway to uninstall all the apps when this uninstaller is executed?

Here's the example .iss file for the master installer, which runs two other installers:

```
#define MyAppName "MasterInstaller"
#define MyAppVersion "1900.1.11"
#define MyAppPublisher "Myself"

[Setup]
AppId={{C0CBD111-111A-11B1-111A-965A8921F38A}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
DefaultDirName=C:\Desktop\test\{#MyAppName}
DisableDirPage=no
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
;PrivilegesRequired=lowest
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
OutputBaseFilename=MasterInstaller

[Types]
Name: "custom"; Description: "Custom installation"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: WpfApp; Description: "WpfApp"; Types: custom
Name: WinFormsApp; Description: "WinFormsApp"; Types: custom

[Files]
Source: "C:\Desktop\innoscripts\WpfAppInstaller.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: WpfApp; Flags: deleteafterinstall
Source: "C:\Desktop\innoscripts\WinFormsAppInstaller.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: WinFormsApp; Flags: deleteafterinstall

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\WpfAppInstaller.exe"; Parameters: "/verysilent /DIR={app}"; Flags: waituntilterminated skipifdoesntexist; StatusMsg: "Installing WpfApp"
Filename: "{app}\WinFormsAppInstaller.exe"; Parameters: "/verysilent /DIR={app}"; Flags: waituntilterminated skipifdoesntexist; StatusMsg: "Installing WinFormsApp..."
```

If it matters, some of these installers install their app in a subfolder of the root folder specified by the master installer.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer to fully control uninstallation via code, so I will use `CurUninstallStepChanged` to uninstall them based on IDs.

Below is just the code to uninstall one app,

```pascal
function CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep): Boolean;
var
  uninstaller: string;
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  Result := True; // Default to true

  if CurUninstallStep = usUninstall then
  begin
    if RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#AppID1}_is1') then
    begin    
      if RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
              'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#AppID1}_is1',
              'UninstallString', uninstaller) then
      begin
        ShellExec('runas', uninstaller, '/SILENT', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);
        if (ErrorCode <> 0) then
        begin
          MsgBox('Failed to uninstall this app. Please restart Windows and run setup again.', mbError, MB_OK);
          Result := False;
        end;
      end
      else
      begin
        MsgBox('Failed to retrieve uninstall string from registry.', mbError, MB_OK);
        Result := False;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hmm, so I'd put this function in my master installer's script, and then keep track of every app installed by it and run this function on each?